# PrintWriter: how to remove BOM mark while printing UTF-8 character

Tags: java, utf-8, printwriter

I am writing using printwriter, and I previously write file with UTF-8 BOM. It causes the csv file having additional whitespace in front of the character. Now I remove these two lines:

```
//          byte[] unicode = {(byte)0xEF, (byte)0xBB, (byte)0xBF};
//          fos.write(unicode);
```

Then my writen csv file has wrong UTF-8 character. what is the workaround?

the full codes of print writer is below:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;



public class FileWriter {
    private static String filenameTemp;

    public static boolean creatFile(String name) throws IOException {
        boolean flag = false;
        filenameTemp = name + "";
        System.out.println("write to file: "+filenameTemp);
        File filename = new File(filenameTemp);
        if (!filename.exists()) {
            filename.createNewFile();
            flag = true;
        }
        else {
            filename.delete();
            filename.createNewFile();
            flag = true;
        }
        return flag;
    }

    public static boolean writeFile(String newStr, String filename) throws IOException {
        boolean flag = false;
        String filein = newStr + "\r\n";
        String temp = "";

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        InputStreamReader isr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(filename);
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
            br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

            buf.append(filein);

            fos = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
            byte[] unicode = {(byte)0xEF, (byte)0xBB, (byte)0xBF};
            fos.write(unicode);
            pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
            
            pw.write(buf.toString().toCharArray());
            pw.flush();
            flag = true;
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            throw e1;
        } 
        return flag;
    }
```

Comment: You don't wana write char array to stream but utf 8 byte representation of string

Comment: @Selvin could you be more specfic to the part that needs to be adjusted?

Comment: "Then I face the wrong UTF-8 character again". What you you mean with that?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi if I remove " byte[] unicode = {(byte)0xEF, (byte)0xBB, (byte)0xBF}; fos.write(unicode);" my writen csv file has wrong UTF-8 character

Comment: Jack: did you try with other editors? It seems that your editor (windows?) will not open csv as UTF-8 by default. Just change *codepage* or *encoding* when reading the csv file. [Note: but many programs requires UTF-8 cvs without BOM]. Your example may seem the usual: two program: two different default way to handle text files. Until Microsoft commits to UTF-8 by default (as the rest of the world), it will be pain handling text file in windows.

Comment: I am using Mac. is the UTF-8 issue related to the removal of " byte[] unicode = {(byte)0xEF, (byte)0xBB, (byte)0xBF}; fos.write(unicode);"

Comment: `pw = new PrintWriter(fos);` ← If you’re creating an PrintWriter on Windows, without specifying a Charset, you are not writing a UTF-8 file.  The default charset on Windows is not UTF-8.

Comment: i am using mac. could u show the full codes here? thanks

Comment: “csv file has wrong UTF-8 character” isn’t very specific.  What characters were you expecting to see?  What did you see instead?  How are you viewing the file?